# How to divide an URL string into parts and insert into variables with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an URL:

```
http://example.org/collections/inventory/cf-size-m+cf-type-capri+cf-vendor-manduka
```

I'm using this script for taking the URL parameters and inserting them into variables:

```
 <script>      
 var getUrlParameter2 = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
var name = getUrlParameter2('myvar');  
             $("#Inventory").html(name);                          
      document.write('<p>URL: '+name+'</p>');
      </script>
```

It works when I have something like this:

```
`http://example.org/collections/inventory/?myvar=resultsblabla`
```

So going back to the URL above:

`http://example.org/collections/inventory/cf-size-m+cf-type-capri+cf-vendor-manduka`

I want to have where `cf-size` the variable and `m` the value and so go on for all the others.

Please let me know if something is not clear so I can modify the question again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with following javascript code:

```js
var url = "http://example.org/collections/inventory/cf-size-m+cf-type-capri+cf-vendor-manduka";

var lstIdxOfSlash = url.lastIndexOf("/");
var paramPart = url.substring(lstIdxOfSlash + 1);
var paramValArray = paramPart.split("+");

var keyValPair = {};

for (var i = 0; i < paramValArray.length; i++) {

  var lstIdxOfDash = paramValArray[i].lastIndexOf("-");
  
  var key = paramValArray[i].substring(0,lstIdxOfDash);
  var val = paramValArray[i].substring(lstIdxOfDash+1);
                                       
  keyValPair[key] = val;                                 
}

console.log(keyValPair);
```

Comment: Im using for the url to turn it into string: 
decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1) 

But looks like it is not working in your code. I have a dynamic url, how to do it in javascript?

Comment: `window.location.search` returns you whatever present in query string i.e. part like `?mayvar=val1$mayvar1=val2` but now in your other case we don't have `?` in url. For this other part just do like `var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);`. I hope this will help you a bit.

Comment: I just noticed you replied me back. Resolved it. 
Used  window.location.href 
Thanks again